# Email validation error using javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using a form validation script found on
http://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/uemfoaoy/13/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ValidateOrderRegistration").validate({
      rules: {

        FirstName: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 1
        },
        LastName: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 1
        },
        Username: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2
        },
        Password: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6
        },
        PasswordConfirm: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6,
          equalTo: "#f-password"
        },
        EmailAddress: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
      },
      messages: {
        FirstName: {
          required: "Please enter your First Name",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters",
        },
        LastName: {
          required: "Please enter your surname",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters",
        },

        Password: {
          required: "Enter a 6 or more digits password",
          minlength: "At least 6 characters"
        },
        PasswordConfirm: {
          required: "Confirm Password Password",
          minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters"
        },
        EmailAddress: {
          required: "Enter an Email",
          email: "Not Valid"
        },
      },


      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.val(error[0].outerText);
      }, //Puts errors as placeholders

    }) //add rules
  $(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("placeholder") == $(this).val())
        $(this).val("");
    }) //validate everything

  $('.cat_textbox').on('click focusin', function() {
    this.value = '';
  }); //cleans fields

  $('#EmailAddress').on('click', function() {
    $('#EmailAddress .error').removeClass('error');
    $(this).addClass('success');
  }); //I tried this!
  $("#EmailAddress").click(function(e) {
    var email = $("#EmailAddress");
    var emailaddressVal = $("#EmailAddress").val();
    var emailReg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    if (!emailReg.test(email.val())) {
      email.addClass("error").focus();
    } else {
      email.removeClass("error");
    } //

    return false;
  });

}); //MAIN VALIDATION
```

Everything works perfectly, but when i click the submit button and if the email was not entered correctly, i cannot modify it. The error "Not Valid" prevents me to do so.

Comment: I think it's because of `return false` in the `$("#EmailAddress").click()` method. That prevents the default action of clicking, so you can't select the element.

Comment: You should first change your email regex. See http://regular-expressions.mobi/email.html to find regex that complies with the RFC

Comment: You shouldn't even need your own email regex. When you specify `email: true` in the validation rules, that uses the plugin's email validaiton. I don't know why you need your own email validation code on top of that.

Comment: What @Barmar said.  If you're using a validation plugin with its built-in validation rules, why would you need code to control email validation messages totally separate from this?  If you don't like the email method of the plugin, you can simply over-ride it without essentially writing a whole separate validation routine.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire problem is caused by this...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.val(error[0].outerText);
}
```

You are setting the value of the field to the validation error message.  Since the fields are validated on every keystroke, you are over-writing the value of the field with the error message as soon as you start typing anything.  You're seeing the problem on the email field simply because this field has a rule that's still triggering a validation error after the first character is typed.

Either the field's displayed value is what the user typed or it's the error message... it can't be both at the same time!

***How do you plan to tell the user that the field is invalid when your error message cannot be seen at the same time as the value typed into the field?***

Here is the default:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
},
```

I've also removed all of the duplicate validation code.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/uemfoaoy/35/**

---

**EDIT**:

As requested, to change the `placeholder` into the error message:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.attr('placeholder', error.text());
},
```

However as I tried to explain above, if the error message is a `placeholder`, then **the user will not be able to see the error message** while he's typing into the field.  A very poor GUI experience IMO.

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/uemfoaoy/36/**

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does solve the problem, but why are "message" and "name" fields not affected :/ i would just like to have placeholders as errors. Would appreciate alot if someone could figure it out. Thank you

Comment: @Elisimo, your request makes no sense!  **If the error messages are placeholders then the user will not be able to see the error message while he's typing into the field.**  Regardless, you could use `element.attr('placeholder', error.text())` to change the `placeholder` text.  http://jsfiddle.net/uemfoaoy/36/

Comment: @Elisimo, I already explained that the other fields only *seem* to be unaffected because validation errors are not triggered.  The `required` and `minlength` rules are satisfied on the first letter and there are no errors after that.  Change the `minlength` rule to something other than `1` and you'll see the same issue appear.